# Custom AuthenticationPrincipal with spring security oauth2 login

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We'd like to migrate an existing spring-security project from custom username/password implementation (UserDetailsService etc) to oauth2 login, using an external identity provider.

However, when logging in through the external provider, the authentication object in the security context is an `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`, with an `OAuth2User` as principal.

Since we're using a custom authentication principal all over in our apps, we'd like to convert the `Oauth2User` to our custom object.

For an oauth2 resource server, there seems to be a `jwtAuthenticationConverter` API which lets you convert the JWtAuthenticationToken to a custom AuthenticationToken, but i have not found something similar for the oauth2 login.

Is there a built in API to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Answering myself here, in case anyone else stumbles upon the same issue:
In your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        // ...
        .oauth2Login()
          .userInfoEndpoint()
          .oidcUserService(myCustomUserDetailsService)
    ;
  }
```